# Install ROS on Linux Mint 17.3?

Tags: ros, linuxmint

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I'm setting up a new computer for running ROS, and I want to use Linux Mint 17.3 as the base.

I've found one thread (http://answers.ros.org/question/118151/install-ros-on-linux-mint-16/) that refers to Linux Mint, but haven't gotten as far as beginning the installation process yet.

Have anyone tried installing ROS on Linux Mint 17.3? Anything different I should be aware of compared to Linux Mint 16?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227754/install-ros-on-linux-mint-17.3?/) by [FrodeL](https://answers.ros.org/users/26101/frodel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-02-28

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jcardenasc93](https://answers.ros.org/users/21826/jcardenasc93/) on 2016-03-18**:
Did you try to install? I think that there is not problem because LM 17.3 still based on Ubuntu 14.04. Just follow the tutorial on the [Wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu) for Indigo version

**Comment by [Mate_Me](https://answers.ros.org/users/26459/mate_me/) on 2016-04-01**:
Hey FrodeL,

did you got an workaround to install ROS (Jade Turtle) on Linux Mint 17.3?

I would like to do the same. Because i got Mint on my PC and won't set it up again with Ubuntu.

Thanks
Mate_Me

**Comment by [FrodeL](https://answers.ros.org/users/26101/frodel/) on 2016-04-01**:
No, I ended up with Ubuntu instead.

**Comment by [Mate_Me](https://answers.ros.org/users/26459/mate_me/) on 2016-04-02**:
Did anyone got run ROS Jade Turtle on Linux Mint 17.3?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-04-02**:
@Mate_Me: could you please not post *answers* when you're not answering a question? Either post a new question, or add a *comment*. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Look here: http://insane-on-linux.blogspot.ru/2014/10/installing-ros-indigo-on-mint-17.html
It's solution!

---

Originally posted by [dividi](https://answers.ros.org/users/27265/dividi/) with karma: 16 on 2016-06-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0